# What is the difference between word "Joy" (when means emotion) and "Amusement" (another emotion)?

Tags: differences

Do they refer to same or different things? If to different things, then does "joy" imply that there is "amusement"? Does "amusement" implicitly mean that there is "joy"?

For example, let's say that I laughed a lot during a specifc comedy. What should I say to say about this comedy in my review, "It was amusing" or "It was joyfull"?

If I understand correctly "amusing" can mean "engaging". Does it mean that in my review of a sad/dramatic/tragic film (with zero comedy involved) I can rightfully say that "the film was amusing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comedy (if it's any good) is *amusing* by definition (it makes you laugh). No, you wouldn't call a sad or dramatic film amusing, though it might have humorous moments. However, an *amusement* can mean a pleasant way to pass the time, without humour necessarily being involved.

*Joy* doesn't have to be a response to humour; it could refer to quite a solemn kind of happiness, perhaps while listening to uplifting music or on an important occasion such as a wedding. A *joyful* film would be one that leaves you feeling happy and positive.